# On exporting SharePoint 2010 to Excel File Unable to export the Date Modified Column

Tags: 2010, column, excel, export

On Exporting SharePoint Document Library to excel file able to export all the columns except the **Modified date** column

Answer (score 0):

Just get more clarification on your issue.

1. Silly question but double check, Is the column visible in view to be exported?
2. Column is exported but no results seen?
3. Any error on export?